# positioning things in android with CSS

Tags: android

Is anyone aware of a custom layout component that can take css to position the buttons etc? Making simple things that fit all screens takes far longer than something similar in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to web style development, check out http://www.phonegap.com

It's a framework that let's you make you app in html/css/js and it builds the apk from that. Can't tell with out knowing what you're building if it will be a good match, but give it a go its probably your best bet till you figure out the android way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a WebView and write your app in HTML. However, I don't recommend that. Once you learn android styles and themes, you will see that it is much more powerful than CSS.

Comment: @user747818 when you have the same skill level in android layout as you have now in css, you will see, that @Amir is right and you don't need longer to achieve the same